# What's the name of this simple, closed, planar curve?

Tags: parametric, curves

A simple, closed, planar curve can be given by the following parametric function:
$$
\gamma(t)=\left(\cos t,\sin t+\frac{\sin^2t}{2}\right)
$$
This function on $t=0$ to $t=2\pi$ gives the following image:
[image]

Is there a name for this particular curve?  It looks a lot like the [bean curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_plane_curve#Bean_curve), but I'm not sure how I could show that the implicit equation for the bean curve is equivalent to the parametric equation I've given above.

Comment: Have you tried factoring $\sin t$ in the second term and then writing $x=\cos t$ and $y= \sin t$? I get then $(x, y(1+y/2))$ but am not sure how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 2):

From the parametric equation $x = \cos t$, so $x^2 = \cos^2 t$. Recall that $\sin^2 x = 1 - \cos^2 x$. We can use this to re-write $y$
\begin{align}
y &= \sqrt{1-\cos^2 t} + \frac{1 - \cos^2 t}{2}\\
y &= \sqrt{1 - x^2} + \frac{1 - x^2}{2}\\
2y + x^2 - 1 &= 2\sqrt{1 - x^2}\\
4y^2 + 4y(x^2 - 1) + x^4 - 2x^2 + 1 &= 4 - 4x^2
\end{align}
This means the implicit equation of this curve is
\begin{equation}
4y^2 - 4y +4x^2y + 2x^2 + x^4 = 3
\end{equation}
Considering that the bean curve does not contain a constant, this may not be a bean curve, BUT maybe with some clever factorization it can be put into the same form. Unfortunately I have not been able to figure out a transformation that (i.e let $x' = x - 2$) that gets rid of the constant.